# Change audio output device with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, audio

Basically i have a program that in some conditions reproduces an audio file... I would like to select the audio output device for a specific program, like i manually do in this menu:

`Settings > System > Audio > App Volume And Device Preferences`[image]

How can i do **(possibly without installing any additional cmdlet)**?

Comment: What are you using to reproduce the audio? I mean the code

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon `(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\New Folder 1\File.wav").Play()` #for some reason it only works with .wav files

Comment: The [`SoundPlayer class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=net-5.0) is meant to only play wav files. As to, "how to select audio output..." have a look at this module: https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Isn't there a way to do that without installing any cmdlet?